# How to prepare Sqlite database for cross platform use

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am building a Xamarin Cross platform application. I want my app to start with an initial database. Does it matter how I create my sqlite database? What I mean is can I use some SQlite Browser app to create it and expect it to work in Android, IOS and UWP? Should I care about what sqlite versions each platform uses?

Comment: I usually use the FF SQLiteManager plugin to create the db, then just copy it into my various projects.  It should be pretty straightforward. I've never had a version conflict

Comment: @Jason When you include the database file in various platform projects, which folder do you store your database file?

Comment: for iOS and WinPhone it can go in the root, for Android put it in Assets

Comment: @Jason In Android, how do you get the path to Assets folder? All examples I saw use AssetManager to read from Assets, but I haven't seen any that shows how to get path to assets?

Comment: in my case I'm copying it from Assets to a writable folder.

Comment: @Jason One last question is that can't you put the db file in xamarin project structure to a writable folder as opposed to copying to a writable folder in code?

Comment: No.  The app bundle is signed so you can't write to it.  There is no installer mechanism to automatically extract files to folders, so you have to do it in code.

Comment: @Jason I followed the Xamarin ToDo app sample. I did everything as the sample showed. When IOS copies my db file to device, it removes all tables. I look at the contents and I see my db file in Library folder, but the size is 0. Have u ever encountered this?

Comment: No.  Either there is a problem with the source file your app bundle, or a problem with your copy code.  You can examine the bundle in your debug directory to verify that the db file is being correctly deployed as part of the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS to copy a database that is added to the root of the Xamarin iOS project, run this code in your `AppDelegate.FinsishedLaunching` method:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine (System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "yourdatabase.db3");
var appDir = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath;
var seedFile = Path.Combine(appDir, "yourdatabase.db3");
if (!File.Exists(dbPath) && File.Exists(seedFile))
{
    File.Copy(seedFile, dbPath);
}
```

And for Android, put the database file in a folder called `Raw` in the `Resources` folder (create the `Raw` folder if it does not exist). Also make sure you add the `ReadExternalStorage` and `WriteExternalStorage` permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  Then run the following code in your `MainActivity.OnCreate` method:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine (System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "yourdatabase.db3"); 
var readStream = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.yourdatabase);
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath)) {
    FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    ReadWriteStream(readStream, writeStream);
}
```

And add the following method to your `MainActivity` class:

```
private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
{
    int Length = 256;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    // write the required bytes
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    }
    readStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

You will then have your database file in a writable location at the path in the `dbPath` variable. Note this code assumes you only want to copy the db file if it does not already exist at the writable location, which seems like a valid assumption. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Note that this link shows how to create a local db with xamarin.Forms getting the dbpath depending on each platform. If you are using mvvmcross, i recomend you not using this solution.

I'm searching to find a way to get the local database path depending on each platform without using xamarin.Forms, as xamarin.Forms has dependencies to old versions of android.support.v4/v7 and this in my case lead to other problems, such as the impossibility to install download cache plugin.

In this same link i provided there's information to do what I'm trying but that code is not working with mvvmcross v4.4.0. in `//winPhone` is not recognizing

### ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path

```
string DatabasePath {
    get {
        var sqliteFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";
        #if __IOS__
        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        string libraryPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder
        var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
        #else
        #if __ANDROID__
        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
        #else
        // WinPhone
        var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);

        //TODO: Add Windows 8.1 and UWP cases here!
        // (use the PCL code above)

        #endif
        #endif
        return path;
    }
```

well this is my expirience is not really an answer but maybe i helped you or you can help me ;) thank you.